# How to debug Python memory fault?

Tags: python, debugging, memory, lxml

*Edit: Really appreciate help in finding bug - but since it might prove hard to find/reproduce, any general debug help would be greatly appreciated too! Help me help myself! =)*

*Edit 2: Narrowing it down, commenting out code.*

*Edit 3: Seems lxml might not be the culprit, thanks! The full script is [here](http://pastebin.com/iar4MhY6).  I need to go over it looking for references. What do they look like?*

*Edit 4: Actually, the scripts stops (goes 100%) in this, the* `parse_og` *part of it. So edit 3 is false - it must be lxml somehow.*

***Edit 5 MAJOR EDIT: As suggested by David Robinson and TankorSmash below, I've found a type of `data` content that will send `lxml.etree.HTML( data )` in a wild loop.  (I carelessly disregarded it, but find my sins redeemed as I've paid a price to the tune of an extra two days of debug! ;)  [A working crashing script is here.](http://pastebin.com/0kCPQz3N)  [(Also opened a new question.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367001/how-to-prevent-lxml-etree-html-data-from-crashing-on-certain-type-of-data)***

> Edit 6: Turns out this is a bug with lxml version 2.7.8 and below (at
>   least). [Updated to lxml 2.9.0](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/), and bug is gone. Thanks also to the fine folks over at [this follow-up question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367001/how-to-prevent-lxml-etree-html-data-from-crashing-on-certain-type-of-data)

I don't know how to debug this weird problem I'm having.
The below code runs fine for about five minutes, when the RAM is suddenly completely filled up (from 200MB to 1700MB during the 100% period - then when memory is full, it goes into blue wait state).

It's due to the code below, specifically the first two lines.  That's for sure.  But what is going on? What could possibly explain this behaviour?

```
def parse_og(self, data):
    """ lxml parsing to the bone! """
    try:
        tree = etree.HTML( data ) # << break occurs on this line >>
        m = tree.xpath("//meta[@property]")

        #for i in m:
        #   y = i.attrib['property']
        #   x = i.attrib['content']
        #   # self.rj[y] = x  # commented out in this example because code fails anyway


        tree = ''
        m = ''
        x = ''
        y = ''
        i = ''

        del tree
        del m
        del x
        del y
        del i

    except Exception:
        print 'lxml error: ', sys.exc_info()[1:3]
        print len(data)
        pass
```

[image]

Comment: Can you link the HTML `data` so we can test the code too?

Comment: `data` is the first 5000 bytes of any HTML doc out there.

Comment: Not to be difficult, but you've tried it with a variety of pages, and it doesn't matter what the data is you pass in?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm parsing about 20 HTML docs per second, and it's "broken html" as it's just exactly the first 5kb of any page.

Comment: @knutole: perhaps there is some attribute of those specific pages that is causing it to break. Can you provide one example?

Comment: @DavidRobinson It's occurred to me, but I doubt it. I mean, it happens too uniformly for that, I think - I've tested 20+ times, and it's always after about 5 minutes.  You'd think it could happen much sooner at least once if it was a matter of randomness.  I'm thinking it has to do with some variables not being emptied and thus filling up memory or something?

Comment: @knutole: Presumably there was something common to those pages (that was why they were chosen?) Anyway, couldn't you just provide any one of them as an example? (I haven't been able to reproduce it either so far).

Comment: @DavidRobinson OK, so like thus for example: http://pastebin.com/a6MyL5dW Really appreciate your interest.

Comment: To reproduce, you'd have to let it run 5-10 minutes, and perhaps more if your RAM or CPU is stronger than mine? (I'm on a small Amazon AWS). Because it runs real fine for a while..!

Comment: What class is `self` a member of?  What is `self.rj`? Does each call to `parse_og()` start with a fresh self?

Comment: @jwpat7  1. `self` is a member of a FastScraper class, which is instantiated for each document. 2. The parsed data is stored in `self.rj` and passed on. 3. And yes.  // When that's said, I've tried the code without adding it to self.rj — and it's still the same. My bad, should have taken it out of the example.

Comment: Having some `lxml` issues on my side. An idea: can you try `print i` in the for loop? Removing one of the `attrib` lines would also help narrow it down.

Comment: Can you reproduce it without the for-loop or if you replace `elem.attrib[name]` with `elem.get(name)`?

Comment: Have you tried running the script under a profiler?

Comment: Does it still happen with the whole `for i in m:` loop commented out?  If so problem likely would be outside the routine, eg if input html text were being kept around (although 20 pages per second of 5000 byte pages for 300 seconds is only 30 megabytes).  If memory use changes by 1GB due to 6000 ops, that's about 167KB per op.  How big is a typical `tree`?  Also, instead of `tree = ''`
and `m = ''` you could say `del m, tree`

Comment: @jwpat7 Yes, thanks! I've tried it now. Still same. See updated question with commented out code. So it's basically just the two lxml lines now.

Comment: @knutole: can you produce a runnable example? One that we could directly copy-paste into our own machine that still produces the issue in your test machine? My current suspicion is that you open lots of files or urlopen and strings read from those files/urlopen are not being freed.

Comment: OK, for those who can stomach the full script: http://pastebin.com/iar4MhY6 Sorry I had to redact credentials.  I'll work on it tomorrow to rule out more suspects. (It's [4 am](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORYKKNoRcDc) here...)

Comment: @DavidRobinson You were right all along. Please see edit 5! Any ideas on how/why/now what?

Comment: @TankorSmash Please see edit 5! Your comments turned out to be supremeley relevant! Any ideas?

Comment: Consider clearing your exception as soon as you handle it, because the entire stack of your program at the time the exception was raised is stored somewhere in `sys` (as evidenced by your ability to retrieve it with `sys.exc_info()`). That is potentially a huge amount of data. I recommend you call `sys.exc_clear()` as soon as you are done handling the exception, if memory usage is important to you.

Comment: @RobM Wow, great tips, thank you. I'm running loads of exceptions as I'm handling very unpredictable data. I'm sure this is an issue, and I'll look into it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Low-level Python debugging with GDB](http://grapsus.net/blog/post/Low-level-Python-debugging-with-GDB). Probably there is a bug in Python interpreter or in lxml library and it is hard to find it without extra tools.

You can interrupt your script running under gdb when CPU usage goes to 100% and look at stack trace. It will probably help to understand what's going on inside script.

Answer (score 2):

it must be due to some references which keep the documents alive. one must always be careful with string results from xpath evaluation. I see you have assigned `None` to `tree` and `m` but not to `y`,`x` and `i` .

Can you also assign `None` to `y`,`x` and `i` .

Answer (score 2):

Tools are also helpful when trying to track down memory problems. I've found [guppy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/) to be a very useful Python memory profiling and exploration tool.

It is not the easiest to get started with due to a lack of good tutorials / documentation, but once you get to grips with it you will find it very useful. Features I make use of:

- Remote memory profiling (via sockets)
- Basic GUI for charting usage, optionally showing *live data*
- Powerful, and consistent, interfaces for exploring data usage in a Python shell

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you find "lost" references with this tool?

Comment: @knutole: With some effort, yes. You can take snapshots of memory state (i.e. before and after the suspected trigger for your problem) and compare them. So you can see just the changes. From there you can obtain the shortest path between global scope and the objecst of interest.