# How to prevent lxml.etree.HTML( data ) from crashing on certain type of data?

Tags: python, html, debugging, lxml

I'm running `etree.HTML( data )` like below for lots of different `data` contents. With a specific `data` conent, however, `lxml.etree.HTML` will not parse it, but go into an infinite loop and consume 100% CPU.

Does anyone know exactly what in this `data` below that can be causing this?  And more importantly, how can I prevent this from happening on an infinite number of random, broken `data`?

> Edit: Turns out this is a bug with lxml version 2.7.8 and below (at
>   least). Updated to lxml 2.9.0, and bug is gone.

*Edit: I know this constitutes an infinite loop, but that's not the bad behaviour I'm getting. It runs fine (as an infinite loop) with a healthy `data` content. With unhealthy `data` content, like below, what happens is that the loop will STOP and RAM will start filling up and when it's full, all CPU goes into WAIT state.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302027/how-to-debug-python-memory-fault) for the original debug.*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#

import sys
from lxml import etree



data = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The 20 Most Despicable Things Gordon Ramsay Has Said and Done, Ranked -- Grub Street New York</title>

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://feedproxy.google.com/nymag/grubstreet" />



    <meta name="Headline" content="The 20 Most Despicable Things Gordon Ramsay Has Said and Done, Ranked" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="april bloomfield, el gordo, frank bruni, gordon ramsay, lawsuits, lists, marcus samuelsson, mario batali, shitlist, spotted pig, sued" />

    <meta name="description" content="Racism, fat-shaming, and vegetarian trickery." />

    <meta name="Byline" content="Sierra Tishgart" />
    <meta name="Type_of_Feature" content="" />
    <meta name="Issue_Date" content="March  8, 2013 12:50 PM" />
    <meta name="related_stories" content="The 20 Most Despicable Things Gordon Ramsay Has Said and Done, Ranked" />
    <meta name="document_type" content="Blog" />
    <meta name="category" content="Lists" />

    <link rel="image_src" href="http://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/grub/2013/03/08/08-gorgon-ramsay.o.jpg/a_146x97.jpg" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://newyork.grubstreet.com/2013/03/20-despicable-things-gordon-ramsay.html" id="canonical" />

    <script>
        var canonicalUrl = "http://newyork.grubstreet.com/2013/03/20-despicable-things-gordon-ramsay.html";
    </script>



    <meta name="content.tags.primary" content=";network - Grub Street,;city - New York City,;tag - lists" />
    <meta name="content.tags" content=";tag - april bloomfield,;tag - el gordo,;tag - frank bruni,;tag - gordon ramsay,;tag - lawsuits,;tag - marcus samuelsson,;tag - mario batali,;tag - shitlist,;tag - spotted pig,;tag - sued" />
    <meta name="content.hierarchy" content="New York City:Grub Street" />
    <meta name="content.type" content="Blog" />
    <meta name="content.subtype" content="Blog Entry" />    


    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="206283005644" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="The 20 Most Despicable Things Gordon Ramsay Has Said and Done, Ranked" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Racism, fat-shaming, and vegetarian trickery." /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/grub/2013/03/08/08-gorgon-ramsay.o.jpg/a_146x97.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://newyork.grubstreet.com/2013/03/20-despicable-things-gordon-ramsay.html" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Grub Street New York" />





    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1020">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.nymag.com/css/screen/grubstreet/grubstreet-core.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.nymag.com/css/screen/section/daily/slideshow.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.nymag.com/css/screen/echo.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.nymag.com/css/screen/loginRegister.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.nymag.com/css/screen/advertising.css" media="all" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://images.nymag.com/gfx/grubst/favicon.ico" />

<style type="text/css">
#adsplashtop,#pushdown {padding:5px 5px;}
#pushdown {border-top:1px solid #737373}
</style>











    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.nymag.com/css/screen/grubstreet/win-ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.nymag.com/css/screen/grubstreet/win-ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->




    <script type="text/javascript">
        var NYM = {};
        NYM.config = {};
        NYM.config.membership = {
            "service":"nym"
        };
        NYM.config.advertising = {
            "sitename":"nym.grubstreet"
        };

    </script>




<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = 'March 12, 2013 12:42:38';
    var currDate=new Date(date);
    var GRUBST = {};
    if (!NYM) {  
        var NYM = {};
        NYM.config = {};
        NYM.config.membership = {
            "service":"nym"
        };
        NYM.config.advertising = {
             "sitename":"nym.grubstreet"
        };
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.nymag.com/scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.nymag.com/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.nymag.com/scripts/ad_manager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.nymag.com/js/2/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.nymag.com/scripts/skinTakeover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.nymag.com/scripts/grubstreet-controls.js"></scr
'''







n = 0
while True:
    n += 1

    tree = etree.HTML( data )
    m = tree.xpath("//meta[@property]")

    print '-', n 
    for i in m:
        print n 
        #print (i.attrib['property'], i.attrib['content'])
```

For quick versions, you can use:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

print("%-20s: %s" % ('Python',           sys.version_info))
print("%-20s: %s" % ('lxml.etree',       etree.LXML_VERSION))
print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxml used',      etree.LIBXML_VERSION))
print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxml compiled',  etree.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION))
print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxslt used',     etree.LIBXSLT_VERSION))
print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxslt compiled', etree.LIBXSLT_COMPILED_VERSION))
```

I've got:

```
OS                  : Ubuntu 12.10 (AWS)
Python              : sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
lxml.etree          : (3, 1, 0, 0)
libxml used         : (2, 7, 8)
libxml compiled     : (2, 7, 8)
libxslt used        : (1, 1, 26)
libxslt compiled    : (1, 1, 26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to parse partial HTML using lxml. It seems to work-around the hanging problem which seems to occur in versions of libxml (2, 7, 8) or older:

```
    parser = LH.HTMLParser()
    parser.feed(data)
    root = parser.close()
    m = root.xpath('//meta[@property]')
```

---

```
import sys
import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.etree as ET

data = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>
     Erased US data shows 1 in 4 missiles in Afghan airstrikes now fired by drone: The Bureau of Investigative Journalism  </title>

 <meta name="description" content="Drone data has been wiped from the Air Force website.">

 <meta name="generator" content="Magicalia 2010" />
 <meta name="google-site-verification" content="bGFVI6kAZGjMNNiS6LGvBDWSGydwyWQI3gogCD4xP50" />

 <link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/style.css?3" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

 <!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/css/lib/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
 <![endif]-->

 <!--[if lt IE 7]>
   <script defer type="text/javascript" src="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/js/pngfix.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <!--[if gte IE 5.5]>
   <script language="javaScript" src="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/js/dhtml.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="The Bureau of Investigative Journalism RSS Feed" href="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/feed/" />
 <link rel="pingback" href="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/xmlrpc.php" />

 <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="The Bureau of Investigative Journalism &raquo; Erased US data shows 1 in 4 missiles in Afghan airstrikes now fired by drone Comments Feed" href="http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/2013/03/12/erased-us-data-shows-1-in-4-missiles-in-afghan-airstrikes-now-fired-by-drone/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mailchimp-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/lib/mailchimp.dev.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='donate-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/lib/donate.dev.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tubepress-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/tubepress/src/main/web/css/tubepress.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='NextGEN-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/css/nggallery.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='shutter-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/shutter/shutter-reloaded.css?ver=1.3.4' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stbCSS-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-special-textboxes/css/wp-special-textboxes.css.php?ver=4.3.72' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='grid-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/big-brother/css/grid.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='reveal-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/big-brother/css/reveal.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='app-css'  href='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/big-brother/css/app.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/plugins/tubepress/src/main/web/js/tubepress.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/js/jquery.cycle.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/js/search.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/js/nav/superfish.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/js/nav/supersubs.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/wp-content/themes/dxw_magicalia/js/home.js?ver=3.5.1'></sc
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("%-20s: %s" % ('Python',           sys.version_info))
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('lxml.etree',       ET.LXML_VERSION))
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxml used',      ET.LIBXML_VERSION))
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxml compiled',  ET.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION))
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxslt used',     ET.LIBXSLT_VERSION))
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxslt compiled', ET.LIBXSLT_COMPILED_VERSION))

    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        print '-', n
        parser = LH.HTMLParser()
        parser.feed(data)
        root = parser.close()
        m = root.xpath('//meta[@property]')
        for i in m:
            print(n)
```

yields

```
% test.py
Python              : sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
lxml.etree          : (2, 3, 0, 0)
libxml used         : (2, 7, 8)
libxml compiled     : (2, 7, 8)
libxslt used        : (1, 1, 26)
libxslt compiled    : (1, 1, 26)
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
...
```

Comment: Do you reckon it could just be the case that AWS is reaching the account limit for cpu and total RAM, then just ignoring stuff from that point forth...

Comment: Well they be damned if that's the case, there is NO docs on this, and I've looked! But in all fairness, I doubt it as I'm getting consistent results with this script - and out of thousands of parsed `data`, the one's that hang are the one's that end with `</scr`. I had a such AWS experience on micro instances though. Tricky debug! ;)

Comment: When I run @knutole's script, my memory usage climbs out of control. With the script above, my memory usage stays constant.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with `lxml.html` - check:

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring( data )
print tree
# <Element html at 0x1bb5530>
print tree.xpath("//meta[@property]")
# []
```

Instead, look at this part....Where you effectively have an infinite loop:

```
n = 0
while True:
    n += 1
    m = [] # never mind if you get results or not - looks like you don't though

    for i in m:
        print n
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Sorry for badly formed question, please see edit.

Comment: If you try the script, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I have - but that's the behaviour I expected - if I try it with just `<!DOCTYPE html><head></head></html>` as the input data - I get exactly the same thing

Comment: @JonClements: Try putting `print(n)` at the end of the while loop. The printing actually stops!? (oops -- knutole already put in such a print statement.)

Comment: Yeah, I don't get normal behaviour at all. In fact, I've got four different `data` now, that all end in `</scr` (as it's broken HTML). And they don't run fine!

Comment: But there are other `data`s also that don't run fine.  Need some way of sanitizing?  But are you guys getting the same behaviour?

Comment: If in an infinte loop, then yes, I get 100% CPU usage on one processor - no memory increase though - if I took out the infinite loop, your data and sample works fine - but just doesn't return any results but your query doesn't match anything anyway

Comment: @knutole: Yes, I'm getting a hanging while-loop. (Evidenced by the print statements stopping.)

Comment: Nope - have let it run for 5 minutes now - maxes one CPU, but doesn't increase shared or resident RAM at all - and if I start a higher priority process on that cpu, that works fine

Comment: I'm using lxml version 2.3.0 -- which is quite old. Running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @unutbu But the print will never run because `m` is always empty... so...?

Comment: @JonClements: See knutole's revised post. There is a print statement outside the for-loop. It is that print statement that is hanging (for me).

Comment: That print works for me - are we sure someone's not using an IDE/code inside an editor here, as they sometimes try to cache all the stdout, which would account for the increased memory usage.

Comment: If by *someone* you mean me, the answer is no :) I'm running it as a script from the terminal. @JonClements: Can you tell us your version of lxml and libxml2?

Comment: I'm running it on Amazon AWS through Coda for OSX. But that doesn't take away from the fact that the script hangs? And it seems it's caused by the ending statement, as described above?  Or is your script running perfectly fine, @JonClements ?  Surely you get an infinite printing of the `n` count of the `While True` loop at least then?

Comment: @JonClements And the content of `data` matters a lot - I mean, that's the issue here, so if you're debugging with your own `data`, that won't be relevant so to speak?

Comment: I'm using your data and my own data, and effectively empty data - and yes - I get the repeated n line by line, but no memory increase - just looking what versions I'm using

Comment: @knutole lxml version is (2, 3, 5, 0) - libxml (2, 8, 0)

Comment: @knutole lxml version is (2,3,0,0) - libxml (2,7,8)

Comment: my etree.lxml version (3,1,0), is that the lxml? libxml is (2,7,8). Updating! =)

Comment: how do you get the lxml version? (not etree.lxml) ?

Comment: @knutole I used `etree.LXML_VERSION`

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, me too.. Weird my version is so high? But of course it could be the libxml. I'll try updating that.  brb

Comment: @JonClements: Btw, voted for you for mod. Hope you run again next time.

Comment: OK, so updated to lxml (2,9,0) and the bug is gone! Thank you @JonClements and @unutbu! I must admit I prefer updating over rewriting my code, although this answer is incomplete.

Comment: @JonClements Can anyone tell me though why my `used` version of lxml is 2.9.0 but my `compiled` version is 2.7.8 ?  I actually still have the bug in my main script, and I'm suspecting this is why?